# How to solve instant insanity puzzle with graphs.

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, puzzle

So I have a 10 cube insanity puzzle, I constructed the graph (I'll post pc later) based on the colors the problem is that there is just way to many lines and nodes to see the solution. Is there any way to find those paths in the graph without trying every permutation. Guess I was unclear. The puzzle is that each cube has 3 different colors, I need to line them up so that each side will have no repeating colors, so with 10 cubes we have 10 unique colors, now when constructing a graph based on problem I need to find a path that will take me through each node but wont repeat same number path (paths are numbered based on cube numbers). so question is how can I find the path from the graph I attached.
[image]

Comment: So there are ten colors?

Comment: according to the wikipedia page the generalization to more than four cubes is np complete http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instant_Insanity

Comment: Probably not. Determining whether a set of Instant Insanity cubes has a solution has been proven to be NP-complete. See https://www.cs.wmich.edu/elise/courses/cs431/icga2008.pdf and other online sources.

Comment: Photos are not useful especially if the numbers cannot be read because they are written to small. Put the data in an appropriate format: 3-column list. The first column is the label of the edge (the cube number) the second is the name of the the vertex of the edge with the smaller number (color) and the third column is the other vertex of the edge. But don't add a photo of the list to the post but add it as code (each line is preceded by four whitespace) so that one can copy and paste the data.

Comment: @SteveKass "Probably not" is probably wrong. Even if it isNP-complete it is possible that it can be solved for input of small size.

Comment: @miracle173 The original poster adked whether there was a solution “without trying every permutation.” I said “probably not,” and gave my reason. What is your reason for believing I’m “probably wrong,” exactli? Do you know other NP-complete problems with non-exhaustive solutions for smallish N? (Briefly, “reference please.”)

Comment: @SteveKass I related your answer to the question "how can I find the path from the graph I attached".